# Choosing root View Controller in UI bootstrap code in AppDelegate (vs viewDidLoad)

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Please forgive me if I am asking something silly (Bit new to iOS and swift). I am trying to integrate MMDrawerController with the help of this tutorial video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-Uwa5v_3sc

In the tutorial, the following code is added to app delegate

```
var window :UIWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!
        let rootViewController = window.rootViewController
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let centerViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Category") as! Category
        let leftViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Menu") as! Menu

        let leftSideNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: leftViewController)
        let centerNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)

        centerContainer = MMDrawerController(centerViewController: centerNav, leftDrawerViewController: leftSideNav)
        centerContainer!.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView;
        centerContainer!.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView;
        window.rootViewController = centerContainer
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

But when i do that it makes the app start with centerViewController but i don't what that behaviour so i moved that code to on viewDidLoad() of centerViewController in a thought that this code is just connecting and initiating the classes but i think this went wrong.

Additionally, For your information I am evoking the centerViewController on a tap of a cell from collection view via this code.

```
var DestViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
            let targetController = DestViewController.topViewController as! Category
```

Now, as soon as this code is called my app freezes and RAM usage of app keeps on increasing until crash.

I put the logs in viewDidLoad() and found that it is being called recursively. Can any one please suggest me how to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Update:

viewDidLoad Function goes like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //
        print("Inside Category")
        var window :UIWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!
        print("1")
        let rootViewController = window.rootViewController
        print("2")
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        print("3")
        let centerViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Category") as! Category
        print("4")
        let leftViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Menu") as! Menu

        let leftSideNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: leftViewController)
        let centerNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)

        centerContainer = MMDrawerController(centerViewController: centerNav, leftDrawerViewController: leftSideNav)
        centerContainer!.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView;
        centerContainer!.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView;
        window.rootViewController = centerContainer
        print("5")
        // window.makeKeyWindow()
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        print("6")
        //
        let tapGestureRecognizerCat = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(Category.btnCategoryTapped(_:)))
        btnCategory.userInteractionEnabled = true
        btnCategory.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizerCat)
        //
        let tapGestureRecognizerSearch = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(Category.btnSearchTapped(_:)))
        btnSearch.userInteractionEnabled = true
        btnSearch.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizerSearch)
        print("7")
    }
```

StackTrace

```
Inside Category
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
Inside Category
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
Inside Category
1
2
3
4
5
6
7 ... and keeps on going like this.
```

Comment: Update your question with the `viewDidLoad` method that is being called recursively. Also post the stack trace showing the recursion.

Comment: @rmaddy Question is updated now.

Comment: Why are you doing anything with the window in `viewDidLoad`? That makes no sense. `viewDidLoad` must ONLY make whatever setup is needed for the view controller's view. That's it. Don't touch the window in there.

Comment: Can you please suggest me where i can do these operations.

Comment: The window's root should be set in the app delegate.

Comment: As the tutorial says to do them in appdelegate but when i do that it makes my app start from this View controller which i don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Moving `UIWindow`/AppDelegate startup code to `viewDidLoad()` is definitely the "coding by shotgun" approach and is essentially asking a View Controller to re-load itself right after it finishes loading.

At a conceptual level, you need to learn the Application Life cycle versus the View Controller life cycle. There are decent Apple developer articles on this. I'll leave the search to you.

Instead, if you're going to override Storyboard startup mechanism (be sure you know what you're getting into -- looks like you're wading into a swamp you're unprepared for), then tell the App Delegate which View Controller IS the entry point you want. What you're looking at there is the code version of the "is Initial View controller" checkbox / right-pointing arrow in Storyboard (attributes Inspector of a View Controller). And of course that code is now ignoring the this Storyboard setting so you need to spell it out in code.

So it would look like:

```
let viewControllerInstanceThatIReallyWant = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TheStoryBoardIDofTheViewControllerThatIReallyWant") as! ClassOfViewControllerThatIReallyWant

...

window.rootViewController = viewControllerInstanceThatIReallyWant
```

And presumably, `ClassOfViewControllerThatIReallyWant` is the identity of a VC in Storyboard, and somehow leads to the relevant `Category` view controller via whatever navigation you've designed.

Comment: I'll surely look for the documentation. :)